# android custom List Adapter repeat old item

Tags: android, android-adapter

this is my custom adapter i use it for first time its work without repeat

```
public class MessageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<MessageList> MessageList;
    private final Context context;


public MessageAdapter(Activity activity, List<MessageList> MessageList, Context c) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.MessageList = MessageList;
    this.context = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return MessageList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return MessageList.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder mHolder;
    final MessageList m = MessageList.get(position);

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {

        if (m.getDir().equals("left")) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.left_message, null);
        } else if (m.getDir().equals("right")) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.right_message, null);

        }

        mHolder = new ViewHolder();



        mHolder.message = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.messages);
        convertView.setTag(mHolder);


    for(String message : m.getMessageList()){


    TextView text = new MyTextView(activity);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    p.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 2);





    text.setLayoutParams(p);
    text.setText(message);
    text.setPadding(8,8,8,8);

    text.setTextSize(14f);


    }

    }


    else {
        mHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }



 Log.d("ffffffffffffffffff",""+m.getMessageList().size());



    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    private LinearLayout message;


}

}
```

this is the result

[image]

but when i receive new data and i want to add it after do

```
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

its repeat the first data and add it to listView see result
[image]

we can see its repeat the data it must add new data i add it to arrayList not repeat old item on it i am sure about my ArrayList its right

at the end just lets see ho9w i add new data 
first when its work without problem

```
  private List<MessageList> Message_List = new ArrayList<MessageList>();
  adapter = new MessageAdapter(this, Message_List, getApplicationContext());
  message_list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

now i will add data for the first time

```
    try {
        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(data);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {


            try {
                JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                MessageList messageList = new MessageList();
                String fname = jsonobject.getString("Fname");
                int user_id = jsonobject.getInt("user_id");
                String message = jsonobject.getString("message");
                String date = jsonobject.getString("date");
                String direction = jsonobject.getString("direction");

                JSONArray MessageArry = jsonobject.getJSONArray("message");
                ArrayList<String> ListMessage = new ArrayList<String>();


                for (int j = 0; j < MessageArry.length(); j++) {
                    ListMessage.add((String) MessageArry.get(j));
                }


                messageList.setUser_id(user_id);
                messageList.setMessage(message);
                messageList.setDate(date);

                messageList.setFname(fname);
                messageList.setDir(direction);
                messageList.setMessageList(ListMessage);

                Message_List.add(messageList);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // JSON error
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

data used its

```
  String data = "[ { \"direction\": \"left\",\"user_id\": \"50\",\"Fname\": \"Mohamed Mohamed\", \"status\":  \"online\" , \"m_status\": \"sent\", \"date\": \"9:20\", \"message\": [\"hello\",\"hahhahah ok ok say hello\",\"-_-\",\"where are \",\"u ?\"] }, { \"direction\": \"right\",\"user_id\": \"50\",\"Fname\": \"Mustafa Naser\", \"status\":  \"online\" , \"m_status\": \"sent\", \"date\": \"10:20\", \"message\": [\"hello\",\"what u want :/\",\"xD\"] }]";
```

when i get new data and i want to append it i add data like this

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonobject1 = new JSONObject(json);




            MessageList messageList = new MessageList();
            String fname = jsonobject1.getString("name");
            int user_id = jsonobject1.getInt("id");
            String message = jsonobject1.getString("message");
            String date = jsonobject1.getString("date");
            String direction = jsonobject1.getString("direction");




            ArrayList<String> ListMessage = new ArrayList<String>();


            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                ListMessage.add(message);
            }




            messageList.setUser_id(user_id);
            messageList.setMessage(message);
            messageList.setDate(date);

            messageList.setFname(fname);
            messageList.setDir(direction);
            messageList.setMessageList(ListMessage);

            Message_List.add(messageList);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

data used its

```
{"message":"qqqqqqqq","id":50,"date":"2016-06-24 04:44:06","name":"medo medo","direction":"left","mode":0}
```

Comment: How do you add data? Do you pass the entire list? If so, clear the list first, and then add again the full list

Comment: `private List<MessageList> Message_List = new ArrayList<MessageList>();messageList.setDir(direction);
                    messageList.setMessageList(ListMessage);

                    Message_List.add(messageList);  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` like this

Comment: As i thought, before adding elements, check if the element is already in the list!

Comment: @LucaNicoletti i update the question i add how i add data for the first time and at the second when repeat

Comment: Look at my answer below, it explains how to update the adapter list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you create a view, you put all messages inside, regardless of whether you have already shown them.

The problem is with the following loop:

```
for(String message : m.getMessageList()) {
     // add a text view for each message
}
```

You need to find a way to check if the message has already been shown and add it to the layout only if it's not there.

Comment: The problem is not there, he's only adding the views here! He need to clear the list, not the views! If he do so, he'll have a 243434534534items in a list, and displaying only some....

Comment: i will try disable it and respone to you

Comment: @LucaNicoletti as Luca Nicoletti say problem not there i disable it same

Comment: @LucaNicoletti This is exactly what I have said - the list holds all the messages, and they are getting added twice.

Comment: The loop you're talking about is used to display the items. And it's wrong to not display items if them are already displayed. It's better to NOT add them to the list.

Comment: @DanailAlexiev can you show me way to check if message  already has been shown ?

Comment: @DanailAlexiev i make boolean varable for check if its add before or not now its work cool thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do as follow:
In your adapterclass add this method:

```
public void updateList(List<MessageList> ){
  this.MessageList = l;
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And, after you fetch the new List, call the `adapter.updateList(newList)` method! It will update itself with the `notifyDataSetChanged();` inside of the method.